# Site going up and down after upgrade, getting 404 nginx errors

Tags: nginx

You'll have to excuse my ineptitude here, I'm still learning Linux and am struggling with this one.  I host a website on AWS running Ubuntu in a LEMP stack and after I upgraded Ubuntu last night, the site is going down randomly and staying down for hours before coming back up again.  I am currently seeing a 404 error on the site.

Everything with the upgrade seemed to go fine, I told it to keep the modified configuration files, so I don't understand what the problem could be.

This the end of my nginx error log:

```
    tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237520 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 51.15.50.51, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "52.86.172.123"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237520 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 51.15.50.51, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "52.86.172.123"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237522 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 51.15.51.63, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "52.86.172.123"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237522 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 51.15.51.63, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "52.86.172.123"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237524 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.90.195.202, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.7692439556121826171875 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "aftercredits.com", referrer: "http://aftercredits.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.7692439556121826171875"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237524 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.90.195.202, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.7692439556121826171875 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "aftercredits.com", referrer: "http://aftercredits.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.7692439556121826171875"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237525 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 54.163.1.126, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.6867620944976806640625 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "aftercredits.com", referrer: "http://aftercredits.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.6867620944976806640625"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237525 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 54.163.1.126, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.6867620944976806640625 HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", host: "aftercredits.com", referrer: "http://aftercredits.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=1481299224.6867620944976806640625"
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237528 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: 51.15.51.63, server: 52.86.172.123, request: "POST /xmlrpc.php HTTP/1.0", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "52.86.172.123"
```

I appreciate all the help I can get.  Thanks!

Edit: Here's the output from the requested command:

```
/var/run$ cd /var/run; sudo find -name 'php*fpm.sock'
./php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

Comment: Does /usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html exist?  Do you have PHP7.0 FPM running?

Comment: Nope, just /usr/share/nginx.  Then under that there is cache and html.

Yes, I am running PHP7.0

Comment: Do this for me, and include ***as an edit to your question*** the output from it:  `cd /var/run; find -name 'php*fpm.sock'`

Answer (score 3):

You've got two issues here.

---

### Issue #1: Missing Error Page.

This is the relevant error lines:

```
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237520 open() "/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ...
```

Somewhere in your configs, you have configured the system to serve the page from `/usr/share/nginx/www/50x.html` for 50X HTTP errors.  This page doesn't exist, so you can't serve it.  You'll have to create that page.

Note that using the default docroot of `/usr/share/nginx/...` is considered a ***pitfall*** because there's no guarantee package managers won't overwrite what's in there.

---

### Issue #2: PHP is running, but it can't find the socket.

These lines:

```
2016/12/09 16:00:24 [error] 1242#1242: *237525 connect() to unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock failed (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) while connecting to upstream, client: ...
```

So, there's some evils here.  PHP7.0 is likely running, but not where you think it is.  A default `php7.0` setup with `php7.0-fpm` will be running in `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock` or `/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock`, but it looks to me like this isn't the case on yours.

First, check to make sure there's actually a socket file running.

```
cd /var/run
find -name 'php*fpm.sock'
```

If it returns something like this, then we know the socket is running, and should be using `/var/run/[path]` for the socket (and you need to update your nginx configuration accordingly):

```
php/php7.0-fpm.sock
```

However, it is possible you're not using a socket file, and need to use the older style method of a TCP socket.  Check to see if a PHP socket is listening on port 9000:

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep 9000
```

If it is, then instead of `unix:...` in your `fastcgi_pass` for your configuration, you need to be using `127.0.0.1:9000`.

If *neither* of these yield results, then you need to make sure `php7.0-fpm` is actually running:

```
sudo systemctl restart php7.0-fpm
```

Then try and repeat the steps to verify if it's running or not.

Comment: Not sure about #1 right now.  Maybe it's carry over from when I first created this installation?  Or was part of the upgrade process?  I'm not sure, I know for a fact that I personally didn't create that, so it must have been done by either an install or upgrade along the line.

For #2, php7.0-fpm is running and in that directory.  
/var/run$ sudo find -name 'php*fpm.sock'
./php/php7.0-fpm.sock

There is no reference to php in my nginx configuration though (/etc/nginx/nginx.conf).

Comment: Well I found the reference for the 50x.html page under /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/wordpress.

Comment: Your nginx configuration is *all* the configuration files including site specific ones like for Wordpress...

Comment: I'll look through and see what I can find.  I'm about ready to just restore from the backup and just not update for now.  I'm also prepared to hire an expert to help with stuff like this and to give the backend a good once-over to make sure things are setup properly.  Any suggestions on finding a good (and cheap) Ubuntu/Nginx/WordPress expert?

Comment: I've looked through all the config files that I could find and am still stuck.  I'm pretty much at a stand still.

Answer (score 0):

I got lucky and was able to figure it out.  I think there are still some other issues, but at least the site's back up and seems stable now.

I read a post that said that the /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf/ listen entry and /etc/nginx/sites-available/ fastcgi_pass need to be the same value.  They wern't.  I tried making them both "/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock", but that didn't work.  So I made them both 127.0.0.1:9000 and that seems to have done the trick.

Why this was all working before and if it was the upgrade that changed these values or did something else connected, I cannot tell you.  But at least it's working now.

Comment: Nevermind, after a few hours it died again.  Back to the drawing board.

Answer (score 0):

## Check status:

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm status
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl status php7.0-fpm
```

## Try with if already running

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl reload php7.0-fpm
```

## Else try with

```
sudo service php7.0-fpm start
```

OR

```
sudo systemctl start php7.0-fpm
```